# how to declare ellipsis defined va_list unused

Tags: c++, c, ellipsis, variadic-functions, unused-variables

I am dealing with the log macros that are defined something like:

```
#define LOGD(...)         rtt_printf(TERMINAL_DEBUG, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGV(...)         rtt_printf(TERMINAL_NORMAL, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

It is all good, but I would like to disable debug logs for release build. But since I am using `-Werror` and `-Wall` I simply get errors when I define **LOGD** without the **rtt_printf()**. Is there any way at all (more dynamic way) other than explicitly declaring **(void)var;** before the LOG call to suppress the unused parameter warnings?

Comment: Unclear to me: are you trying to define an empty macro?

Comment: Can you show the code & macro definition producing the error, as well as the exact error text?

Answer (score 0):

You might have

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define LOGD(...) do {} while(0)
#else
#define LOGD(...) do {rtt_printf(TERMINAL_DEBUG, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
                      } while(0)
#endif
```

following the convention on `NDEBUG` used by [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html)

If you want to use the arguments to make your compiler happy and have it check the arguments, you could try (in the `NDEBUG` case)

```
#define LOGD(...) do { if (false) printf(__VA_ARGS__); }while(0)
```

So the [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) won't emit any call to `printf` (if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to pass `-Wall -O2` at least to `g++`)

BTW, I would suggest instead (for the debugging case without `NDEBUG`):

```
#define LOGD(Fmt,...) do { rtt_printf(TERMINAL_DEBUG, "%s:%d " Fmt "\n", \
                                      __FILE__, __LINE__, ##_VA_ARGS); } while(0)
```

then use `LOGD("x=%d", x)` in your code. This would show the source line position.

At last, in genuine C++11, you'll better use output streams from [`<ostream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream) and code (for the debugging case):

```
#define LOGOUTD(Out) do {std::clog << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ \
                         << " " << Out << std::endl;}while(0)
```

and later use `LOGOUTD("x="<<x)`. Then, if you have defined appropriate `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Foo&)` for your class `Foo`, you could have `x` being an instance of it.

PS. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154264/841108) for the explanation about `do{`...`}while(0)` in macros.